# Ability to get the "index" (or ordinal value) for each array entry in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In a `data` column in BigQuery, I have a JSON object with the structure:

```
{
 "sections": [
   {
     "secName": "Flintstones",
     "fields": [
       { "fldName": "Fred", "age": 55 },
       { "fldName": "Barney", "age": 44 }
     ]
   },
   {
     "secName": "Jetsons",
     "fields": [
       { "fldName": "George", "age": 33 },
       { "fldName": "Elroy", "age": 22 }
     ]
   }
 ]}
```

I'm hoping to `unnest()` and `json_extract()` to get results that resemble:

```
id  | section_num  | section_name | field_num | field_name | field_age
----+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------
1   | 1            | Flintstones  | 1         | Fred       |  55
1   | 1            | Flintstones  | 2         | Barney     |  44
1   | 2            | Jetsons      | 1         | George     |  33
1   | 2            | Jetsons      | 2         | Elroy      |  22
```

So far, I have the query:

```
   SELECT id,
          json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.secName') as section_name,
          json_extract_scalar(curField, '$.fldName') as field_name,
          json_extract_scalar(curField, '$.age') as field_age
     FROM `tick8s.test2` AS tbl
LEFT JOIN unnest(json_extract_array(tbl.data, '$.sections')) as curSection
LEFT JOIN unnest(json_extract_array(curSection, '$.fields')) as curField
```

that yields:

```
id  | section_name | field_name | field_age
----+--------------+------------+-----------
1   | Flintstones  | Fred       |  55
1   | Flintstones  | Barney     |  44
1   | Jetsons      | George     |  33
1   | Jetsons      | Elroy      |  22
```

**QUESTION: I'm not sure how, if possible, to get the `section_num` and `field_num` ordinal positions from their array index values?**

(If you are looking to duplicate my results, I have a table named `test2` with 2 columns:

- `id` - INTEGER, REQUIRED
- `data` - STRING, NULLABLE

and I insert the data with:

```
insert into tick8s.test2 values (1, 
'{"sections": [' ||
       '{' ||
         '"secName": "Flintstones",' ||
         '"fields": [' ||
           '{ "fldName": "Fred", "age": 55 },' ||
           '{ "fldName": "Barney", "age": 44 }' ||
         ']' ||
       '},' ||
       '{' ||
         '"secName": "Jetsons",' ||
         '"fields": [' ||
           '{ "fldName": "George", "age": 33 },' ||
           '{ "fldName": "Elroy", "age": 22 }' ||
         ']' ||
       '}]}'
);
```

)

Comment: read [Flattening arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want `with offset`?

```
SELECT id,
       json_extract_scalar(curSection, '$.secName') as section_name,
       n_s,
       json_extract_scalar(curField, '$.fldName') as field_name,
       json_extract_scalar(curField, '$.age') as field_age,
       n_c
 FROM `tick8s.test2` tbl LEFT JOIN
       unnest(json_extract_array(tbl.data, '$.sections')
             ) curSection WITH OFFSET n_s LEFT JOIN
       unnest(json_extract_array(curSection, '$.fields')
             ) curField WITH OFFSET n_c;
```